# How do I remove brackets or ignore them coming out of Scatter-Gather using Dataweave?

Tags: java, mule, dataweave

I have a  with 1..n  objects inside of returns from 3 different services. I call each of the 3 services with Scatter-Gather. My aggregate becomes:

```
[
 <?xml version='1.0' encoding='windows-1252'?>
 <policy-group>
    </policy>
    </policy>
 </policy-group>,
 <?xml version='1.0' encoding='windows-1252'?>
 <policy-group>
   </policy>
   </policy>
 </policy-group>,
 <?xml version='1.0' encoding='windows-1252'?>
 <policy-group>
   </policy>
   </policy>
 </policy-group>
]
```

The brackets in the string XML message are causing errors in my Dataweave. Does anyone know how to get around this issue?

My error is ..

Unexpected character '[' (code 91) in prolog; expected '<'
 at [row,col {unknown-source}]: [1,1] (com.ctc.wstx.exc.WstxUnexpectedCharException).

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

Add Combine-Collection after Scatter-Gather, it will combine all result into one. For some cases issue occurs when the result is not combined.

Comment: Sulthony, it didn't work. I was getting XML that I could log, but now it went back to 3 BinaryInputStreams and qualified class names in the logger. That also persisted when I removed the Combine Collections. This has been really difficult to resolve.

Comment: What is the expected input of DataWeave? All those three XMLs as a single input, or proceed them one by one?

If it is a single input, then add *Object to XML* transformer after the *Scatter-Gather*. It will wrap all those three XMLs as one XML document.

If it will be proceed one by one, then add *Collection Splitter* flow control after the *Scatter-Gather*. It will process each XML document.

Comment: This was was resolved with Message Enricher and the flatten function in Dataweave

Answer (score 0):

If you don't want to use transformer or write some special code to do this. You can simply do like below

Use Expression Component

```
<expression-component doc:name="Expression"><![CDATA[
message.payload= org.mule.util.StringUtils.removeStart(message.payload,"[");
message.payload= org.mule.util.StringUtils.removeEnd(message.payload,"]"); 
]]>
</expression-component>
```

Or can directly do in Set Payload

```
 <set-payload value="#[message.payload= org.mule.util.StringUtils.removeStart(message.payload,&quot;[&quot;);message.payload= org.mule.util.StringUtils.removeEnd(message.payload,&quot;]&quot;)]" doc:name="Set Payload"/>
```